# Segmentation fault when passing char** in c

Tags: c

first timer here, please be gentle.

I'm attempting to pass an array of strings that's been dynamically allocated within a function back to the main. When I attempt to access it in the main, I'm getting a segmentation fault.

I've tried to include the relevant code without what I'm hoping is the irrelevant parts.

Main calls the function "readFileToWordsArray".
"readFileToWordsArray" calls the function "convertWordListToArray".

I don't understand why, but it'll happily let me pass my char** (dynamically allocated array of strings) from "convertWordListToArray" to "readFileToWordsArray" and I can access it as you'd expect. However, when I attempt to pass it further back to main, and try to access it there, I get a segmentation fault. Even if I just read the first element (which works fine in the other functions) with:

```
printf("Word read from array is : \"%s\"\n", strInputFileWords[0]);
```

Thanks!!!!

```
void convertWordListToArray(char **WordArray, StringNodePtr currentPtr)
{
    ...
    while ( currentPtr != NULL )    /* while not the end of the list */
    {
        WordArray[intWordCounter]= malloc(strlen(currentPtr->strWord) + 1);
        strcpy(WordArray[intWordCounter], currentPtr->strWord);
    }
}

bool readFileToWordsArray( char **strWordArray, char *strWordFile, int *intWordArrayCount)
{
    char **strInternalWordArray;
    ...
    strInternalWordArray=malloc(intWordCounter * sizeof(char*) );
    convertWordListToArray(strInternalWordArray, startPtr);
    printf("Word read from array strInternalWordArray is : \"%s\"\n", strInternalWordArray[0]);
    strWordArray = strInternalWordArray;
}

int main ( int argc, char *argv[] )
{
    char **strInputFileWords;
    ...
    if (readFileToWordsArray(strInputFileWords, strInputFile, &intInputFileWordsCount))
        {

        printf("words loaded correctly. count is %d\n\n", intInputFileWordsCount);

        for (i=0;i<intInputFileWordsCount;i++)
        {
            printf("Word read from array is : \"%s\"\n", strInputFileWords[0]);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your code has to many Errors or is incomplete, fix it (provide us a code which compile) and come back. You should Turn on your compiler settings

Comment: did you notice your `bool` function did not return anything?

Comment: You must allocate `char **strInputFileWords;` in `main` or pass `char ***` and pass `&strInputFileWords` to your functions and allocate it there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In `readFileToWordsArray`, you're assigning a value to `strWordArray`, which is a parameter to a function.  Therefore, changes to this variable are not visible to the calling function.

If you want `strInputFileWords` in main to be modified in `readFileToWordsArray`, you need to pass its address:

```
if (readFileToWordsArray(&strInputFileWords, strInputFile, &intInputFileWordsCount))
```

Then your function would be defined as:

```
bool readFileToWordsArray( char ***strWordArray, char *strWordFile, int *intWordArrayCount)
```

And you would dereference `strWordArray` and assign to that:

```
*strWordArray = strInternalWordArray;
```

Comment: Darn, just beat me to it! Note that strInputFileWords is actually never initialized, so when you try to use it, who knows what address it's trying to access -- very likely memory address 0 which usually isn't mapped.

Comment: Or just some random garbage address, as `strInputFileWords` has an address itself, but there is no guarantee what is there until it is initialized. (agreed - It's tough to beat a 'machine gun' typist... )

Comment: Thanks. The thing that threw me was that it worked passing back the char** from convertWordListToArray to readFileToWordsArray, but not from readFileToWordsArray to main.

I realise now this is because in convertWordListToArray I worked directly with the char** that was passed in, whereas in readFileToWordsArray I worked with a temporary variable and then copied the pointer, which as you say, is passed by value instead of by reference.